# Why don't recipes use the word "of" as in "1 cup milk" instead of "1 cup of milk"?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

It really confuses me and I can't seem to find the reason for that. It's amazing how it apparently never bothered anyone.

Comment: But some recipes **do** use *of*.

Comment: Perhaps a cup of milk isn’t everyone’s cup of tea.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's excluded because it adds no value to the instructions. Historically recipes have either been hand-written or printed which means limited space on a page. Removing words that add no value is a logical efficiency gain (especially when writing by hand). I would guess this approach has just grown to become the standard.

Comment: It might also be considered redundant. If every line in a recipe used *of* it could become tiring to see the word used so often when it's not required for understanding in the first place.

Comment: @JasonBassford I agree. I think I even had that in my answer at some point but it didn't make through the editing process 

Answer (score 3):

This is just idiomatic English and has been for many centuries. Take for example part of this recipe "[f]or to make gyngerbred" from circa 1400:

> Tak & put half a quart hony in a bras panne
>
> (*Take and put half a quart honey in a brass pan*)

(Via the [MED](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED31072/track?counter=1&search_id=3632860) and [another site](https://aneala.lochac.sca.org/arts/food-and-drink/cream-custard-tarts/))

That same recipe also calls for you to "tak a pound of pouder gyngere" (*take a pound of powdered ginger*), so that shows that both forms were used simultaneously.

A similar thing happened with words like “dozen”. The preposition “of” was originally used, for example in “For ix dozen of breede” (*For 9 dozen of bread*) from 1425. Gradually, this form was replaced by the version without “of” as in “x dosen Curlewes” (*10 dozen curlews*, a type of bird) from 1450. (Both quotes via the [MED](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED12413/track?counter=1&search_id=3641582).)